# Excel Predictive Text

Tags: microsoft-excel, automation, autocomplete

I'd like to have Excel do predictive text based on a column on another sheet.  I don't want to use the 'Drop Down' via data validation, since it is a long list of items and I can look up the value manually faster than finding it in this list.

Any thoughts on how to do this would be appreciated.  I've considered writing a vba script, but I'd really prefer to not deal with that headache.

Answer (score 0):

What about `Alt + ↓` ?

If it is on list, it will automatically highlight the closest matched one.

[image]

If not, it will highlight nothing.

[image]

Comment: That's interesting...  That's exactly what I would like!  But my data entry is on a separate sheet from my lookup table.  So, when I hit alt-down the list populates with values from my data-entry form, instead of my lookup table.  There is something here though, I'll have to do some more research on this function.  Thank you!